# Joining a table that get 500k+ new rows and selecting the newest in a fast query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a users table and a calls table there are about 500k new rows inserted into the calls table every day. Each call record has a user_id column and i have about 700 users but what i need to do is select every user and get their most recent call created_at time. What is the fastest way of doing this?

Comment: GROUP BY combined with MAX(created_at time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select u.*, MAX(c.created_at)
from users u
    left join calls c on u.user_id = c.user_id
group by u.user_id
```

The `GROUP BY` will only work if user_id is the primary key.

Alternative answer:

Use `NOT EXISTS` to pick only the latest call:

```
select *
from users u
    left join calls c on u.user_id = c.user_id
where not exists (select 1 from calls c2
                  where c2.created_at> c.created_at
                    and c2.user_id = c.user_id)
```

Comment: It needs additional `JOIN` to get a call details, which might be a bit tricky if `(user_id, created_at)` tuple is not guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: @zerkms, more or less true.

Comment: @zerkms, According to ANSI/ISO SQL you can't. (Perhaps Postgresql do things their own way here.) But I was considering the selected columns, i.e. a column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function, or be functionally dependant on the group by columns.

Comment: But probably I see what you mean: `select u.*` - that's another postgresql extension that indeed would require it.

Comment: @zerkms, actually "functionally dependant" has been included in the SQL standard for a while now. (But very few vendors have implemented it.)

Comment: Yep, now I see that what you referred to is `SELECT u.*` not the `GROUP BY` itself (that exact phrase and the very initial version that did `SELECT user_id` confused me). My apologies.